# how to properly remove qwidgets and update/reload that widget

Tags: python, pyqt5

Trying to remove a qwidget and replace it with another qwidget and then reload the layout the qwidget is a part of

I've already tried the update and removeWidget method, though i could've used it improperly

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import sys

validUser = False
app = None

class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        screen = app.primaryScreen().size()
        self.title = 'Restaurant Application'
        width = screen.width()
        height = screen.height()
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.table_widget = MyTableWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table_widget)
        self.initUI()

        self.show()

    def initUI(self):
        # window
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        # statusbar
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Welcome to el restaurante')

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print('Mouse coords: ( %d : %d )' % (event.x(), event.y()))


class MyTableWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        # Initialize tab screen
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.login = QWidget()
        self.menu = QWidget()
        self.checkOut = QWidget()
        self.tabs.resize(500, 200)

        # Add tabs
        self.tabs.addTab(self.login, "Login")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.menu, "Menu")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.checkOut, "Check out")

        # Create login tab
        self.login.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.menu.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        # login text
        self.loginPrompt = QLabel("Please provide a valid login")
        self.loginPrompt.setFixedSize(315,30)
        self.loginPromptFont = QFont("Times", 27, QFont.Bold)
        self.loginPrompt.setFont(self.loginPromptFont)
        self.login.layout.addWidget(self.loginPrompt)
        self.login.setLayout(self.login.layout)

        # Create textbox
        self.loginTextbox = QLineEdit(self)
        self.loginTextbox.returnPressed.connect(self.on_click_login)
        self.loginTextbox.setFixedSize(170,20)

        # Create a button in the window
        self.loginButton = QPushButton('Login button', self)
        self.loginButton.clicked.connect(self.on_click_login)
        self.loginButton.setFixedSize(100,40)
        self.login.layout.addWidget(self.loginTextbox,alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.login.layout.addWidget(self.loginButton,alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)


        #widget code i use to decide which widget to add
        self.menuInvalidUserLogin = QLabel("Please login in to view")
        self.menuValidUserLogin = QLabel("Here's the menu")

        if(validUser):
            self.menu.layout.addWidget(self.menuValidUserLogin)
        else:
            self.menu.layout.addWidget(self.menuInvalidUserLogin)
        self.menu.setLayout(self.menu.layout)

        # Add tabs to widget
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def on_click_login(self):
        global validUser
        global app
        textboxValue = self.loginTextbox.text()
        if(textboxValue.lower() == 'pass'):
            validUser=True
            #the solutions i have been trying
            self.menu.layout.removeWidget(self.menuInvalidUserLogin)
            self.layout.removeWidget(self.menuInvalidUserLogin)
            self.menu.layout.update()

            QMessageBox.question(self, 'Response', "Login successful: Welcome", QMessageBox.Ok,QMessageBox.Ok)
        else:
            validUser=False
            QMessageBox.question(self, 'Response', "Login unsuccessful: EXPLAIN YOURSELF", QMessageBox.Ok,QMessageBox.Ok)
        self.loginTextbox.setText("")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = App()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

expected results should be that the old widget is removed, new widget is added and then the layout those widgets are a part of is refreshed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you were expecting?

Also, is there a specific reason why you are using global variables in your class? It is bad practice, you should make them class members.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(App,self).__init__()
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
        screen = app.primaryScreen().size()
        self.title = 'Restaurant Application'
        width = screen.width()
        height = screen.height()
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.table_widget = MyTableWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table_widget)
        self.initUI()
        self.show()

    def initUI(self):
        # window
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        # statusbar
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Welcome to el restaurante')

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print('Mouse coords: ( %d : %d )' % (event.x(), event.y()))


class MyTableWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyTableWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.validUser = False

        # Initialize tab screen
        self.tabs = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.login = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.checkOut = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tabs.resize(500, 200)

        # Add tabs
        self.tabs.addTab(self.login, "Login")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.menu, "Menu")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.checkOut, "Check out")

        # Create login tab
        self.login.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.menu.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        # login text
        self.loginPrompt = QtWidgets.QLabel("Please provide a valid login")
        self.loginPrompt.setFixedSize(315,30)
        self.loginPromptFont = QtGui.QFont("Times", 27, QtGui.QFont.Bold)
        self.loginPrompt.setFont(self.loginPromptFont)
        self.login.layout.addWidget(self.loginPrompt)
        self.login.setLayout(self.login.layout)

        # Create textbox
        self.loginTextbox = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.loginTextbox.returnPressed.connect(self.on_click_login)
        self.loginTextbox.setFixedSize(170,20)

        # Create a button in the window
        self.loginButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Login button')
        self.loginButton.clicked.connect(self.on_click_login)
        self.loginButton.setFixedSize(100,40)
        self.login.layout.addWidget(self.loginTextbox,alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.login.layout.addWidget(self.loginButton,alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)


        #widget code i use to decide which widget to add
        self.menuInvalidUserLogin = QtWidgets.QLabel("Please login in to view")
        self.menuValidUserLogin = QtWidgets.QLabel("Here's the menu")

        if(self.validUser):
            self.menu.layout.addWidget(self.menuValidUserLogin)
        else:
            self.menu.layout.addWidget(self.menuInvalidUserLogin)
        self.menu.setLayout(self.menu.layout)

        # Add tabs to widget
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def on_click_login(self):
        textboxValue = self.loginTextbox.text()
        if(textboxValue.lower() == 'pass'):
            self.validUser=True
            for i in reversed(range(self.menu.layout.count())): 
                widgetToRemove = self.menu.layout.itemAt(i).widget()
                self.menu.layout.removeWidget(widgetToRemove)
                widgetToRemove.deleteLater()
            self.menu.layout.addWidget(self.menuValidUserLogin)
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Response', "Login successful: Welcome", QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok,QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok)
            self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(1)
        else:
            self.validUser=False
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Response', "Login unsuccessful: EXPLAIN YOURSELF", QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok,QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok)
        self.loginTextbox.setText("")

def main():        
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: yes, this worked! could you explain what the code is doing with the setParent(None)? How does the code know to call the method used for the menu tab without the 'update()' method. Do you know why the removeWidget method wasn't working? And i'm also getting these warnings about "QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to MyTableWidget "", which already has a layout"

Comment: @ShahrozImtiaz I updated the code to remove the widget from the layout list as well as the GUI. You are not technically deleting the object you are just setting it as a top-level widget. Does the updated code still give you warnings about the QLayout? Also, where is it throwing this error?

Comment: @ShahrozImtiaz removeWidget just removes the widget from the layout but doesn't actually delete the object, it makes it where the layout can't use it anymore but the object is still there.

Comment: @ShahrozImtiaz if my answer solved your question, please upvote and mark as solved.

Comment: yes the warning gets printed to console, so i dont know where/what is causing it

Comment: @Shahroz  Imtiaz is the warning occurring with the same code as I posted or did you add to it, what exactly are you doing to produce the warning?

Comment: @ShahrozImtiaz I've updated the code to remove the widgets (layouts,labels,buttons) parent. When you add a widget to a layout it it will automatically set itself a parent to whatever widget is holding it. It is not necessary to explicitly give a widget a parent. I prefer to actually provide the classes (QtCore,QtWidgets,QtGui) explicitly instead of just importing all, as it increases readibility. Try it out and let me know if this is still producing a warning.